# javascript performance memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

In my web application, when I load a js module, I will meet a performance problem. I can hardly do the drag-drop/click operation after the page run a few time (10+ mins).

So I think this must be caused by the js file, it may cause the memory leak, but I have not idea how to find the problem.

Any one can give me some suggestion?

Comment: Show some code and we may be able to help.

Comment: First you should give us more info about the problem, a piece of code, the plugins you are using, in which browser you are experiencing the issue, ecc..

Comment: The js file I load contains more than 600 lines,I do not know which should be posted here.

Comment: Isn't there any tools to monitor the js memory?

Comment: At least try to have it working as is on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), or give us a link to the site if it's publicly accessible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to use valgrind with the browser if you want to check for a memory leak.

Comment: this is the accepted answer? LOOOOOOOOL. you can't use valgrind for javascript.

Comment: Maybe you can't but I and he can?

Answer (score 1):

I would give [DynaTrace Ajax Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about one of the ways you can find memory leaks with Chrome's Developer Tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling.

Also, this article tells you about how memory leaks can take place in JavaScript, in general: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/index.shtml. The usual case is when there are circular references between JavaScript world and the DOM world. The JavaScript world does have a GC that knows how to clean up circular references, but the DOM world has an entirely different GC. Combining the two worlds in some ways (which look innocuous at first) can lead to memory leaks even in modern browsers.

If the memory fills up quickly it is often due to detached DOM trees. If these are canvas elements or images, they can take much more memory than they appear to in the profiler tool (because the image data is store somewhere else). This is just one example, of course - there are many ways in which you can fill up the memory quickly.